# Replace Data Loader with a Web Service

Tags: webservices, data-loader

I was planning to build an automated Data Loader process that would read a CSV file and populated the Account and Opportunity entities. There would also be some Account matching on existing records.

Data Loader would have been a simple method to achieve that, however we have been directed that we must use a web service instead in order to comply with a future ESB strategy (the source system would also change from producing a CSV to calling the web service).

Defining a corresponding web service end point is simple in Salesforce.com, however are there any good strategies or AppExchange offerings that could replicate the configuration based Data Loader process and avoid APEX coding as much as possible?

(I'm aware of third party products such as Mulesoft and Informatica Cloud. Ideally I don't want to add a new product into the mix)

Comment: I heard Skyvva is quite versatile and installs from AppExchange right into your org.

Comment: doing a custom solution means you have to take various limits into account - especially CPU time and heap size as large CSVs may/will cause you to hit these limits.

Comment: The Skyvva data loader appears to be a cloud based version of SFDC Data Loader. It doesn't appear to expose a web service to interface with?

Comment: @Andrew You should probably contact SKYVVA support (support@skyvva.com) directly about calling their webservices.  Would you like to share a bit of info about your use case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several AppExchange offerings. What they offer is a platform native installed version, versus a external client using the Force.com APIs. This is similar to the Data Import Wizard that you can fire up on the platform. The ones I have seen, including Skyvva, use an import file. There is a lot of functionality that these packages provide from a data cleansing perspective. Things like de-dup, external ID matching, error handing, etc.

Given the fact that *file export is no longer acceptable*, and you do not want to add in any other products,  your only choice is to build out an orchestration on your own ESB using the SOAP or bulk REST API. Hopefully your mandated ESB/ETL tooling has a connector to simplify this task, and provide some cleansing abilities.